# how to autoupdate category by the amount of products in django model

Tags: python, django, database

I have a model of the category with title and count and I also have another model called Products which has category as one of its foreign-key. How can I auto-update the category count field by the number of products that comes under the same category?

```
class Category(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length = 20)
    count = models.IntegerFIeld()

class Product(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length = 20)
    category = models.ForeignKey(Category, on_delete = models.CASCADE)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can either override save method or write a signal to auto-update the field, i.e.:

```
class Category(models.Model):
    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.count = self.product_set.count()
        super().save(*args, **kwargs)
```

or with signals:

```
from django.dispatch import receiver
@receiver(post_save, sender=Category)
def category_post_save(sender, instance, *args, **kwargs):
    instance.count = instance.product_set.count()
    instance.save()
```

But I would suggest you using a calculated `property`:

```
class Category(models.Model):
    ...

    @property
    def count(self):
        return self.product_set.count()
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want to keep the field `count` I recommend you use **signals**. You should use `post_signal` and `pre_signal` (to get the previous category from a query) on the model **Product**.

Here are the signals:

```
@receiver(signals.pre_save, sender=Product)
def product_pre_save_signal(sender, instance, *args, **kwargs):
    if instance.id:
        previous_instance = Product.objects.get(id=instance.id)
        if previous_instance.category != instance.category:
            instance.previous_category = previous_instance.category

@receiver(signals.post_save, sender=Product)
def product_post_save_signal(sender, instance, created, *args, **kwargs):
    if not created:
        if hasattr(instance, "previous_category"):
            if instance.previous_category:
                instance.previous_category.count -= 1
                instance.previous_category.save()
            if instance.category:
                instance.category.count += 1
                instance.category.save()
    else:
        if instance.category:
            instance.category.count += 1
            instance.category.save()
```

Another recommendation for this situation is, make it a read-only field(add `editable=False` to the field declaration), so no one can edit it from Django admin or serializer.

**But** I highly recommend you remove the field because it's hard to keep this field sync with the table *Product*, so calculate the value each time.

You can have almost any query that is related field `count` over Category or Product, so don't worry:)